# Histograms in R with a "more" categorie, similar to MS Excel

Tags: r, excel, histogram

Consider the following frequency data:

```
> table(income)
income
   3    5    6    7    8 5000 
   2    7    2    2    2    1
```

When I type

```
 >hist(income)
```

I get the following histogram

[image]

So as you can see, the fact that most income values are concentrated around 5 and there is one value quite distant from the others makes the histogram not look very good. MS Excel can consider the 5000 value as of another category, so the data would like this instead:

```
> table(income)
income
   3    5    6    7    8 more 
   2    7    2    2    2    1
```

So plotting this as a histogram would look much better, so you can see the frequency within a shorter range:

[image]

Is there anyway to do this either with the `hist()` function or others functions from lattice or ggplot2? I do however, don't want to overwrite the values that exceed a certain threshold, so as I do lose any information.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The graph you show is not a histogram. It's a (pretty bad) barplot, which is not useful if you want to deduce anything about the distribution. Instead you should consider a transformation. E.g., you could log-transform your values.

Comment: This is the standard plot from MS Excel, I see no point in transforming it just to show what I mean to do in R. Also, this is just a sample data, the original contains continuous values with more than 800k observations

Comment: My point is, that you shouldn't do what you suggest to do. It will result in a bad graph (note how the categories jump from 3 to 5 and then increment in steps of 1).

Comment: I do know what you mean, but that's not the EXACT ouput I want, you're clinging to the point that the MS Excel plot IS indeed (I do agree with you) a bad graph, but the whole point is how to get a "more" category (I'm ignoring the other categories for now) without overwriting any information.

Comment: I'm not talking about the exact Excel output, but about (i) using a categorial x-axis instead of a continuous x-axis and (ii) having a "more" category. Both are bad ideas.

Comment: (i) The categorical axis is not part of the desired output, it should be just as a regular histogram. (ii) Having a more category is not a bad idea, but log-transforming the data is. It doesn't make any sense to make a presentation about logs of income, but about income. I do however need to know how many cases are beyond a certain threshold to deal with them separately.

Answer (score 3):

Data generation:

```
income <- c(rep(3,2), rep(5,7), rep(6,2), rep(7,2), rep(8,2), 5000)
```

Function for preparing data for plotting:

```
nice.data <- function(x, threshold=10){
  x[x>threshold] <- "More"
  x
}
```

Plotting:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x=nice.data(income))) + xlab("Income")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: redmode, thanks for the help, but I should have specified that I do not want to lose any information from my data, so overwriting "5000" with "more" doesn't do the trick as I expect

Comment: Updated to more flexible version.